# 'XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND', 'XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT' and 'HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM' alternatives in POI 3.17

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using poi-3.6 and I need to update my source files to poi 3.17. I need to know 'XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND', 'XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT' and 'HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM' alternatives in poi 3.17.

```
    CellStyle fontBoldedCell = ExcelCommon.getFontBoldedCell(workbook);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    row = sheet.createRow(currrow++);
    cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Total Records");
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(count);
    cell.setCellStyle(ExcelCommon.getAligneCell(workbook, null, XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT));

    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBold(true);
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(font);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    return style;    

    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    style.setFont(font);
    style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
```

Comment: Use google... just type `apache poi 3.17 solid foreground` and you will find it. Same goes for others as well

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills